# Unexpected results from SQL query with BETWEEN timestamps

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, heroku, timestamp-with-timezone

I have created a little test app to track down a problem I experienced with Postgres on Heroku: http://snippi.com/s/xd511rf

As you can see in line **49**, I want to retrieve all entries created *today*. This would be the first two items of my test data with the Ruby Gem *DataMapper*.

When I run this app on my notebook (Ubuntu 12.10, HP, Ruby 1.9.3) everything I get this result, which is right:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "text": "Working on some awsomenewss",
    "category": 0,
    "starttime": "2013-03-21T15:56:00+01:00",
    "endtime": "2013-03-21T18:26:00+01:00",
    "creation": "2013-03-21T16:15:21+01:00"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "text": "facebooking",
    "category": 0,
    "starttime": "2013-03-21T20:48:00+01:00",
    "endtime": "2013-03-21T22:26:00+01:00",
    "creation": "2013-03-21T16:15:21+01:00"
}
]
```

In my debug console this SQL query is logged:

```
SELECT "id", "text", "category", "starttime", "endtime", "creation" 
  FROM "entries" 
  WHERE "starttime" 
    BETWEEN '2013-03-21T00:00:00+00:00' 
      AND '2013-03-21T23:59:59+00:00' 
  ORDER BY "id"
```

But after pushing the app to Heroku a very strange error occurrs. When I run it now (http://afternoon-everglades-4239.herokuapp.com/) this is the response:

```
[]
```

Why is it empty?

The data is definitely in the database which is proved by this Dataclip from Heroku: https://dataclips.heroku.com/hygziosyxwperyctwfbhjzgbzhbj

Also when I run the SQL command manually via ´heroku pg:psql´ it actually works with this output:

```
 id |            text             | category |      starttime      |       endtime       |      creation       
----+-----------------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------
  1 | Working on some awsomenewss |        0 | 2013-03-21 15:56:00 | 2013-03-21 18:26:00 | 2013-03-21 16:15:21
  2 | facebooking                 |        0 | 2013-03-21 20:48:00 | 2013-03-21 22:26:00 | 2013-03-21 16:15:21
(2 rows)
```

The logs do not contain any errors or further information.
I have used a *Remote Heroku PostgreSQL Database* in both cases (Production and Local).

So why does this not work?

Comment: Your table creation script with exact type declaration is **essential** for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the **data type** of the columns and your **time zone**. You may be confusing [**`timestamp with time zone`** and **`timestamp`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170).

Looks like you have `timestamp` in your table, but query with `timestamptz`. This way, it all depends on the local time zone of your session (which defaults to the time zone of the server if not specified otherwise.)

Switch both to `timestamptz`, or `timestamp` if time zones are completely irrelevant to you. (If in doubt, use `timestamptz`.)

Not the cause of your problem, but your query should probably be:

```
SELECT id, text, category, starttime, endtime, creation 
FROM   entries 
WHERE  starttime >= timestamp '2013-03-21' -- defaults to 00:00 time
AND    starttime <  timestamp '2013-03-22'
ORDER  BY id
```

`a BETWEEN x AND y` is **almost always wrong** for `timestamp` types due to fractional numbers! What would your query do with `starttime = '2013-03-21T23:59:59.123+00'`?

Comment: If you look at the [data clip](https://dataclips.heroku.com/hygziosyxwperyctwfbhjzgbzhbj) you'll see that there are no time zones in the timestamp values so I'd guess that the columns are `timestamp` rather than `timestamptz`. That would also line up with the usual "`timestamp` and everything is in UTC in the database" approach that originates with Rails (i.e. another bit of hidden nastiness because the Rails people don't understand relational databases).

Comment: I'd say it more strongly **`BETWEEN` is almost always wrong** regardless of type. 90% of uses of `BETWEEN` I see in the wild really want to be the inclusive-start exclusive-end interval test you wrote explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much for this execllent answer. I will try something out this evening and will answer if everything ok.