# Best way to count rows by arbitrary time intervals

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, aggregate-functions, generate-series

My app has a `Events` table with time-stamped events.

I need to report the count of events during each of the most recent `N` time intervals. For different reports, the interval could be "each week" or "each day" or "each hour" or "each 15-minute interval".

For example, a user can display how many orders they received each week, day, or hour, or quarter-hour.

1) My preference is to dynamically do a single SQL query (I'm using Postgres) that groups by an arbitrary time interval. Is there a way to do that?

2) An easy but ugly brute force way is to do a single query for all records within the start/end timeframe sorted by timestamp, then have a method manually build a tally by whatever interval.

3) Another approach would be add separate fields to the event table for each interval and statically store an `the_week` `the_day`, `the_hour`, and `the_quarter_hour` field so I take the 'hit' at the time the record is created (once) instead of every time I report on that field.

What's best practice here, given I could modify the model and pre-store interval data if required (although at the modest expense of doubling the table width)?

Comment: a rough idea here but 
SELECT Count(Event) From Table Where  2 > Datediff(mm,Date, currentDate) > 1

Comment: I dont see a datediff for postgres, nor do I see how to do N < function() < M

Comment: check out these 2 posts, i 'think' this is what you are looking for? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623358/group-by-data-intervals AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045600/postgresql-sql-group-by-time-interval-with-arbitrary-accuracy-down-to-milli-sec

Comment: A little cursory reading, the subtraction of two dates yields an interval in Postgresql.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Assuming this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE event(
  event_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, ts timestamp NOT NULL
);
```

Note the data type `timestamp`. All following examples match this data type. When dealing with `timestamptz`, adjust accordingly. See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

### Postgres 14 or newer

Since Postgres 14 we have the convenient function [**`date_bin()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN). See:

- [What is the fastest way to truncate timestamps to 5 minutes in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299342/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-truncate-timestamps-to-5-minutes-in-postgres/75160734#75160734)

To get 1 row for every time slot *with data* in the table:

```sql
SELECT date_bin('15 min', e.ts, '2018-05-01') AS start_time
     , count(e.ts) AS events
FROM   event e
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Time slots without entries in the table go missing in the result.
Note that the "origin" ('2018-05-01' in the example) is only for alignment, not curtailment.

To get 1 row for every time slot since 2018-05-01:

```sql
SELECT start_time, COALESCE(events, 0) AS events
FROM  (
   SELECT generate_series(timestamp '2018-05-01', max(ts), interval '15 min')
   FROM   event
   ) g(start_time)
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT date_bin('15 min', e.ts, '2018-05-01'), count(e.ts)
   FROM   event e
   WHERE  e.ts >= '2018-05-01'  -- filter early (optional)
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) e(start_time, events) USING (start_time)
ORDER  BY 1;
```

The set-returning function [**`generate_series()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) can be used to generate a full set of rows.
Time slots without entries in the table are filled in with a count of 0.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/U-p-otob)

### Postgres 13 or older

Original answer, obsolescent, but with more explanation.

#### Basic solution

This query counts events for any arbitrary time interval. 17 minutes in the example:

```sql
WITH grid AS (
   SELECT start_time
        , lead(start_time, 1, 'infinity') OVER (ORDER BY start_time) AS end_time
   FROM  (
      SELECT generate_series(min(ts), max(ts), interval '17 min') AS start_time
      FROM   event
      ) sub
   )
SELECT start_time, count(e.ts) AS events
FROM   grid       g
LEFT   JOIN event e ON e.ts >= g.start_time
                   AND e.ts <  g.end_time
GROUP  BY start_time
ORDER  BY start_time;
```

The query retrieves minimum and maximum `ts` from the base table to cover the complete time range. You can use an arbitrary time range instead.

Provide ***any* time interval** as needed.

Produces one row for *every* time slot. If no event happened during that interval, the count is `0`.

Be sure to handle **upper and lower bound** correctly. See:

- [Unexpected results from SQL query with BETWEEN timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551740/unexpected-results-from-sql-query-with-between-timestamps)

The window function [`lead()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) has an often overlooked feature: it can provide a default for when no leading row exists. Providing [`'infinity'`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-SPECIAL-TABLE) in the example. Else the last interval would be cut off with an upper bound `NULL`.

#### Minimal equivalent

The above query uses a CTE and `lead()` and verbose syntax. Elegant and maybe easier to understand, but a bit more expensive. Here is a shorter, faster, minimal version:

```sql
SELECT start_time, count(e.ts) AS events
FROM  (SELECT generate_series(min(ts), max(ts), interval '17 min') FROM event) g(start_time)
LEFT   JOIN event e ON e.ts >= g.start_time
                   AND e.ts <  g.start_time + interval '17 min'
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

#### Example for *"every 15 minutes in the past week"`*

Formatted with [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html).

```
SELECT to_char(start_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'), count(e.ts) AS events
FROM   generate_series(date_trunc('day', localtimestamp - interval '7 days')
                     , localtimestamp
                     , interval '15 min') g(start_time)
LEFT   JOIN event e ON e.ts >= g.start_time
                   AND e.ts <  g.start_time + interval '15 min'
GROUP  BY start_time
ORDER  BY start_time;
```

Still `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` on the underlying timestamp *value*, not on the formatted string. That's faster and more reliable.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c7e87204a217f1abf376ab17da8d08a2)*

Related answer producing a *running count* over the time frame:

- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#8194088)

Comment: I'm still trying to grok this, but it appears another brilliant aspect of this approach is it handles the "zero count" issue... eg, if there is no data in an interval it reports 0 rather than omitting the interval (as other approaches do).

Comment: Seriously, in the history of SO that's the Most. Amazing. Answer. Ever.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thank you for provided code, it almost perfectly fits in my case, except that I have FK field group_id by which it should be grouped.

As example: 

`events of group_id = 1 occurred 20 times from now() - 7 days to now(); events of group_id = 2 occurred 1 times from now() - 7 days to now();`

Can you help me with this? From what I've tried - simple group by on group_id does not give me the right queryset.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter do you know how to filter these by a rails scope?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I find this query is quite slow with millions of records. Is there any way to improve the performance? Which indexes would be most efficient here?

Comment: @coolboyjules: I updated various details in this old answer. Indexes depend on your exact use case, but aggregating a whole table with millions of rows cannot be very fast - and index support is limited for this scenario. You might start a new question, comments are not the place. You can always link to this one for context.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks for your edit. It is really appreciated and I will give your approach a try without the CTE. I've posted my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221842/slow-left-join-on-cte-in-postgresql

Comment: Just for others reference, here is the same `generate_series` logic abstracted using a function. https://gist.github.com/gajus/b10235149427c1c746d94d86c1befc5d