# Generate month data series with null months included?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, date-arithmetic

I have a simple calendar year monthly data set returned but I know I will have missing months (i.e. no data).

I found this answer here:

[Best way to count records by arbitrary time intervals in Rails+Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576794/best-way-to-count-records-by-arbitrary-time-intervals-in-railspostgres/15577413)

It's close but I do not understand the `JOIN USING` syntax.

I have my side figured out for the most part:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(activity_tasks.start_date, 'MON') AS month,
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM activity_tasks.start_date) AS month_num,
SUM(cost_planned) FILTER (WHERE activity_tasks.aasm_state IN ('open', 'planned' ) )  AS planned,
SUM(cost_actual) FILTER (WHERE activity_tasks.aasm_state IN ('closed' ) ) AS actual
FROM "activity_tasks"
WHERE activity_tasks.start_date >= '2020-01-01' AND activity_tasks.start_date <= '2020-12-31'
GROUP BY month, month_num
ORDER BY month_num
```

Which gets me:

```
+-------+-----------+---------+--------+
| month | month_num | planned | actual |
+-------+-----------+---------+--------+
| NOV   | 11        | NULL    | 123    |
| DEC   | 12        | 500     | NULL   |
+-------+-----------+---------+--------+
```

I just want to join:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT to_char(m, 'MON') AS mmm
   FROM generate_series('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31', interval '1 month') m
) m
```

in to one simple expression and have a full JAN-DEC dataset including the empty months.

**Bonus Side Question:** is there a more elegant SQL to build the `generate_series('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31', interval '1 month')` array of months and set my `WHERE activity_tasks.start_date >= '2020-01-01' AND activity_tasks.start_date <= '2020-12-31'`?  In my case the default is Jan 1 of a given year BUT there may be a case where the accounting fiscal year is some other month and looking to avoid duplicate logic here and perhaps just feed in a single start date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate all starts of months with `generate_series()`, then bring the table with a `left join`:

```
select 
    to_char(d.start_date, 'mon') as month,
    extract(month from d.start_date) as month_num,
    sum(cost_planned) filter (where t.aasm_state in ('open', 'planned' ) )  as planned,
    sum(cost_actual)  filter (where t.aasm_state = 'closed') as actual
from generate_series('2020-01-01'::date, '2020-12-01'::date, '1 month') d(start_date)
left join activity_tasks t
    on t.start_date >= d.start_date and t.start_date < d.start_date + '1 month'::interval
group by start_date
order by start_date
```

You can easily change the arguments of `generate_series()` to accomodate a different fiscal year.

Comment: Works great . I have a side question which should have been part of the question.  I have a parent table `activities` that has a `type` column.  I want to join that table also and add a `where` clause to filter out specific types. etc.

Comment: I just updated my question.  I removed that second join from my first question because I thought it would be trivial to add that back in.  I thought that was an easy join to add back in but I am obviously missing something here as when I do I get the old results and the 'empty' months don't show up anymore.

Comment: @DanTappin: you should not be modifying the question after answer answers were posted (and accepted). If you have a new question, then you should ask *a new question*.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I will revert it and post a second question 

Comment: FYI - new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65313068/chained-join-not-filtering-as-expected. Hopefully a easy answer for you.

Comment: Ended- up figuring it out with a sub-select for the JOIN.  Your answer here cleared the way for that.  Thanks.