# Chained join not filtering as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a related question here:

[Generate month data series with null months included?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65280988/generate-month-data-series-with-null-months-included)

When I posted I omitted the second join thinking it was trivial and not impact my question - I was wrong there.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(activity_tasks.start_date, 'MON') AS month,
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM activity_tasks.start_date) AS month_num,
SUM(cost_planned) FILTER (WHERE activity_tasks.aasm_state IN ('open', 'planned' ) )  AS planned,
SUM(cost_actual) FILTER (WHERE activity_tasks.aasm_state IN ('closed' ) ) AS actual
FROM "activity_tasks"
INNER JOIN "activities"."id" = "activity_tasks"."activity_id"
WHERE "activities"."type" = 'My Type' AND activity_tasks.start_date >= '2020-01-01' AND activity_tasks.start_date <= '2020-12-31'
GROUP BY month, month_num
ORDER BY month_num
```

Which gets me:

```
+-------+-----------+---------+--------+
| month | month_num | planned | actual |
+-------+-----------+---------+--------+
| NOV   | 11        | NULL    | 123    |
| DEC   | 12        | 500     | NULL   |
+-------+-----------+---------+--------+
```

The accepted answer on the related had me try various modifications like adding:

```
LEFT JOIN activities a
ON a.id = t.activity_id AND a.type = 'My Type'
```

which results in (not filtering out just `My Type`):

```
+-------+-----------+---------+--------+
| month | month_num | planned | actual |
+-------+-----------+---------+--------+
| JAN   | 1         | NULL    | NULL   |
| FEB   | 2         | NULL    | NULL   |
| MAR   | 3         | NULL    | NULL   |
| APR   | 4         | NULL    | NULL   |
| MAY   | 5         | NULL    | NULL   |
| JUN   | 6         | NULL    | NULL   |
| JUL   | 7         | NULL    | NULL   |
| AUG   | 8         | NULL    | NULL   |
| SEP   | 9         | NULL    | NULL   |
| OCT   | 10        | 0       | 0      |
| NOV   | 11        | 125     | 123    |
| DEC   | 12        | 1414    | 0      |
+-------+-----------+---------+--------+
```

Tried this:

```
ON a.id = t.activity_id
WHERE a.type = 'My Type'
```

Which gets me the correct filtered results but I lose the filtered results again:

```
+-------+-----------+---------+--------+
| month | month_num | planned | actual |
+-------+-----------+---------+--------+
| NOV   | 11        | NULL    | 123    |
| DEC   | 12        | 500     | NULL   |
+-------+-----------+---------+--------+
```

I am looking for this - the filtered tasks with the 'null' months also:

```
+-------+-----------+---------+--------+
| month | month_num | planned | actual |
+-------+-----------+---------+--------+
| JAN   | 1         | NULL    | NULL   |
| FEB   | 2         | NULL    | NULL   |
| MAR   | 3         | NULL    | NULL   |
| APR   | 4         | NULL    | NULL   |
| MAY   | 5         | NULL    | NULL   |
| JUN   | 6         | NULL    | NULL   |
| JUL   | 7         | NULL    | NULL   |
| AUG   | 8         | NULL    | NULL   |
| SEP   | 9         | NULL    | NULL   |
| OCT   | 10        | NULL    | NULL   |
| NOV   | 11        | NULL    | 123    |
| DEC   | 12        | 500     | NULL   |
+-------+-----------+---------+--------+
```

I have tried all types of JOINS for the second join.  Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Can you please add the result that you actually want?

Comment: Sorry - I normally re-read to ensure I have clearly asked an specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Realized I need a sub-select like this:

```
SELECT 
  UPPER(TO_CHAR(d.start_date, 'mon')) AS month,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM d.start_date) AS month_num,
  SUM(t.cost_planned) FILTER (WHERE t.aasm_state IN ('open', 'planned' ) ) AS planned,
  SUM(t.cost_actual)  FILTER (WHERE t.aasm_state = 'closed') AS actual
FROM GENERATE_SERIES('2020-01-01'::date, '2020-12-01'::date, '1 month') d(start_date)
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT t.*
FROM activity_tasks t
LEFT JOIN activities a
ON a.id = t.activity_id
WHERE a.type = 'My Type'
) AS t ON t.start_date >= d.start_date and t.start_date < d.start_date + '1 month'::interval
GROUP BY d.start_date
ORDER BY d.start_date
```